# Office 365 ATP Safe Links detects our url/domain accidentially as malicious

Tags: office365

I have the problem that for some reason the Office365 ATP "Safe Links" feature classifies our url/domain as malicious.

The problem occured 2 days ago. Nothing changed at our side. 
I already opened a ticket for that but no response till now.
Using another subdomain helps - but that is no sustainable solution.

1. How can I remove our domain from the List of untrusted links
   globally (local whitelisting is no option of course)
2. How can I get to know why our url is considered as malicious?
3. Does anybody know more about the algorithm which the url check uses to
   classify a domain/url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the list of suspicious links is not visible anywhere and no dedicated request for deletion can be made.
A Support Ticket in Office365 is the only way to do it.

After I made some pressure, we were removed. Apparently it helps to make sure that no pictures and content are loaded on the linked page without HTTPS.

Maybe this page will also help you to identify your problem with messages or other stuff:

https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/